# printf formatting of strings in python

Tags: python, bash, formatting

Is there a way to do `printf` formatting to strings in Python? Something like this where the count `x` is rewritten every time instead of echoing to a new line.

```
x=0
while [[ $x -lt 10 ]]; do
    x=$((x+1))
    printf '%s\r'"Processing page ${x}"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: You mean like [this](https://pyformat.info/)?

Comment: The answer to this question will depend on the version of Python in use. Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm using Python2

Comment: Thanks, the linked question gave me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 (Daiwei Chen's answer covers Python 2.6+ also):

```
import time
x = 0
while x < 10:
    x += 1
    print('\rProcessing Page {0}'.format(x), end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Adding a carriage return to the beginning and removing the new line from the end with `end=''` will overwrite the current line.

Comment: You might mention that your solution is specific to Python3, or (even better) provide solution(s) that work in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Yes, I remembered that just now

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, the print function takes in an additional argument for the `end` parameter.

```
>>> print('foo', end='')
foo

>>> for i in range(10):
print('foo', end='')
foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
```

Of course, if you're using Python >= 2.6, you'll need to import `print_function` from `__future__`.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out.